# traverse through whole table and check span tag atrribute name

Tags: javascript, jquery

*HTML:*

```
<table id="mytable">    
<tr>
<td class="cssred"><span name='478'>john</span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="cssred"><span name='478'></span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="cssred"><span name='478'></span></td>
</tr>
 <tr>
<td class="cssred"><span name='521'></span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="cssred"><span name='522'></span></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

*JavaScript:*

```
$(this).find('span').attr('name');
```

i have to traverse through whole table and check any span tag atrribute name value be 478 then make its parent cell class `cssgreen`.

Comment: If your problem solved, please click the accepted answer, For Users to know which is correct answer...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$("#mytable td:has(span[name='478'])").toggleClass("cssred cssgreen");
```

or

```
$("#mytable span[name='478']").parent().toggleClass("cssred cssgreen");
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/E55jb/

Comment: The OP said 'make its parent cell class cssgreen' which would imply removing cssred, I think

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$('#mytable span').each(function() {
   if($(this).attr('name') == "478") $(this).parent().removeClass('cssred').addClass('cssgreen');
});
```

or easier

```
$('#mytable span[name=478]').parent().removeClass('cssred').addClass('cssgreen');
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
  $('span[name="478"]').each(function(){
     $(this).parent().removeClass("cssred");
     $(this).parent().addClass("cssgreen");
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**

```
  $("#mytable span").each(function() {
       if($(this).attr("name") == "478"){ // check if name=478
       $(this).parent().removeClass("cssred"); // remove red bg
       $(this).parent().addClass("cssgreen"); // add green bg
  });
```